# Asistente de consultas MYSQL/PHP/JQuery

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

Estoy trabajando en un reporte que me muestre en una tabla HTML los resultados de una consulta SQL

Puedo obtener los datos muy facil con PHP

```
$link=new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=dbname','user','pass',array(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION));

$resultado=$link->query("SELECT users.nombre, sucursales.nombre FROM users LEFT JOIN sucursales ON sucursales.idsucursales=users.idsucursales");

        $headers="";
        $T_campos=$resultado->columnCount();
        for($x=0;$x<$T_campos;$x++){
            $meta=$resultado->getColumnMeta($x);
            $headers[$x]=$meta['name'];
        }
        foreach($resultado as $row){
            $local=array();
            for($con=0;$con<$T_campos;$con++){
                $local[$con]=$row[$con];
            }
            $jsondata[]=$local;
        }
```

Pero los resultados que obtengo son siempre iguales en columnas del mismo nombre

Por ejemplo en esta consulta

```
SELECT **users.nombre, sucursales.nombre** FROM users LEFT JOIN sucursales ON sucursales.idsucursales=users.idsucursales
```

La vista que obtengo de resultados es algo asi

```
nombre | nombre
user x | sucursal x
user x | sucursal x
```

Como puedo hacer para obtener los nombre completos con todo y tabla en esta consulta sin utilizar alias "AS"

Algo como esto

```
users.nombre | sucursales.nombre
user x | sucursal x
user x | sucursal x
```

La idea es poder crear un reporteador donde se pueda ingresar cualquier SQL y este arroje las tablas y campos a los que pertenece cada columna del query

Una de las ideas que van saliendo es a la par de hacer la consulta como tal, hacer una decodificacion misma del SQL

Me explico

Desempaquetar el "`SELECT tabla1.campo1, tabla2.campo2 FROM tabla1, tabla2...`" en un arreglo

> tabla1.campo1 -> tabla1
>
> tabla2.campo2 -> tabla2

Y recorrer mediante "schema" para validar que este campo corresponda a esa tabla

Gracias a nuestro amigo A. Cedano por sus aportes

**ACTUALIZACION**

```
function multiexplode($delimiters,$string){
    $ready=str_replace($delimiters,$delimiters[0],$string);
    $launch=explode($delimiters[0],$ready);
    return $launch;
}
function LimpiaCadena($SQL){
    return preg_replace('/[ \t]+/',' ',preg_replace("/[\r\n]+/"," ",$SQL));
}
function EliminaEspacios($SQL){
    return trim(preg_replace("/[[:blank:]]+/"," ",$SQL));
}

function GetCampos($link,$SQL){
    function Get_Pos($SQL,$OMITE=array()){
        $SQL=strtoupper($SQL);
        $C=array(" LEFT JOIN "," RIGHT JOIN "," INNER JOIN "," WHERE "," GROUP BY "," HAVING "," ORDER BY ",);
        $Pos=0;
        foreach($C as $row){
            if(!in_array($row,$OMITE)){
                $Pos=strpos($SQL,$row);
                if($Pos!==false) return $Pos;
            }
        }
        return strlen($SQL);
    }
    function Sep_Tabla($valor,$sep="."){
        if(strpos($valor,$sep)!==false){
            $sp=explode($sep,$valor);
            $sp[0]=EliminaEspacios($sp[0]);
            $sp[1]=EliminaEspacios($sp[1]);
            return array($sp[0],$sp[1]);
        }else{
            $valor=EliminaEspacios($valor);
            return array("",$valor);
        }
    }

    $CAMPOS=array();
    $ALIAS=array();

    $SQL=LimpiaCadena($SQL);
    $PSelect=strpos(strtoupper($SQL),"SELECT ");
    $PFrom=strpos(strtoupper($SQL)," FROM ");
    if($PSelect!==false && $PFrom!==false){
        $PSelect+=7;   
        $np=$PFrom-$PSelect;
        $cam=substr($SQL,$PSelect,$np);
        //OBTENGO CAMPOS
        $ACam=explode(",",$cam);
        foreach($ACam as $key=>$row){
            $Pos=strpos(strtoupper($row)," AS ");
            //SI TIENE ALIAS
            if($Pos!==false){
                $nv=substr($row,0,$Pos);
                //$iv=substr($row,$Pos+4,strlen($row));
                //if($iv!="") $ACampos[$key]=$iv;
                $row=EliminaEspacios($nv);
            }
            $ca=Sep_Tabla($row);
            $CAMPOS[]=$ca;
        }
        //OBTENGO TABLAS
        $up=Get_Pos($SQL);
        $PFrom+=6;
        $np=$up-$PFrom;
        $tab=substr($SQL,$PFrom,$np);
        $ATab=explode(",",$tab);
        foreach($ATab as $row){
            $row=LimpiaCadena($row);
            $Pos=strpos(strtoupper($row)," ");
            //SI TIENE ALIAS
            if($Pos!==false){
                $sp=explode(" ",$row);
                $sp[0]=EliminaEspacios($sp[0]);
                $sp[1]=EliminaEspacios($sp[1]);
                if($sp[1]!="") $ALIAS[$sp[1]]=$sp[0];
            }
        }
        //OBTENGO RELACIONES
        $nsql=substr($SQL,$up,strlen($SQL));
        $up2=Get_Pos($SQL,array(" LEFT JOIN "," RIGHT JOIN "," INNER JOIN "));
        $np=$up2-$up;
        $join=substr($SQL,$up,$np);
        //OBTENGO TABLAS RELACIONADAS
        $output=multiexplode(array(" LEFT JOIN "," RIGHT JOIN "," INNER JOIN "),$join);
        $S=array();
        foreach($output as $key=>$row){
            $alt=multiexplode(array("ON ","on "),$row);
            $S[]=$alt[0];
        }
        foreach($S as $key=>$row){
            $Pos=strpos(strtoupper($row)," ");
            //SI TIENE ALIAS
            if($Pos!==false){
                $sp=explode(" ",$row);
                $sp[0]=EliminaEspacios($sp[0]);
                $sp[1]=EliminaEspacios($sp[1]);
                if($sp[1]!="") $ALIAS[$sp[1]]=$sp[0];
            }
        }
        //AGREGO A SALIDA
        foreach($CAMPOS as $key=>$row){
            $tabla=$row[0];
            $campo=$row[1];
            $tabla=EliminaEspacios($tabla);
            $campo=EliminaEspacios($campo);
            if($ALIAS[$tabla]!="") $tabla=$ALIAS[$tabla];
            if($campo=="*"){
                //$link=new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname='.$BASE,'root','12345678');
                $r_campo=$link->query("DESCRIBE ".$tabla);
                foreach($r_campo as $row){
                    $SCampos[]=$tabla.".".$row[0];
                }
            }else{
                $SCampos[]=$tabla.".".$campo;
            }
        }
    }
    return $SCampos;
}
```

Este código logra resolver consultas básicas con `SELECT`, `LEFT JOIN`, `RIGHT JOIN`, `INNER JOIN`, Alias en Tablas y Campos

```
$SQL="SELECT
users.*, 
u.nombre AS 'sucu', 
s.nombre 
FROM users u
LEFT JOIN sucursales s ON s.idsucursales=users.idsucursales";

$SCampos=GetCampos("test",$SQL);
foreach($SCampos as $row){
    echo $row."<br>";   
}
```

Este seria el resultado

```
users.idusers
users.nombre
users.fecha
users.idsucursales
users.idgrupo
users.nombre
sucursales.nombre
```

Aun le falta mucho para poder usar querys mas complejos pero creo que funciona como ejemplo, que opinan??? como lo mejoramos??? como agregamos sub querys???

Aca algunas capturas de la aplicacion

[image: Captura Principal]

[image: Tablas y campos draggables y consulta SQL ajustable al contenido previo]

[image: Esto es lo que queremos obtener]

Como es un código algo extenso para postearlo, lo subí a un servidor por si les interesa jugar con el

[DESCARGAR CODIGO](http://facturatefacil.com/SQL.zip)

Gracias por su tiempo :)

**Actualizacion 5/9/18**

Nuestro amigo @A. Cedano nos da un gran aporte.

```
<?
$SQL="SELECT u.nombre, s.nombre FROM  users u LEFT JOIN sucursales s ON s.idsucursales=u.idsucursales";

$link=new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test',"root","12345678",array(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION));
$stmt=$link->prepare($SQL);
$stmt->execute();
$meta = $stmt->getColumnMeta(0);
echo "<pre>";
var_dump($meta);
echo "</pre>";


$con = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '12345678', 'test'); 
$stmt = $con->prepare($SQL)or die("failed statment"); 
$stmt->execute(); 
$meta = $stmt->result_metadata(); 
echo "<pre>";
var_dump($meta);
echo "</pre>";
?>
```

Aplicándolo no da los siguiente resultados

```
array(7) {
  ["native_type"]=>
  string(4) "BLOB"
  ["pdo_type"]=>
  int(2)
  ["flags"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(4) "blob"
  }
  ["table"]=>
  string(1) "u"
  ["name"]=>
  string(6) "nombre"
  ["len"]=>
  int(-1)
  ["precision"]=>
  int(0)
}
object(mysqli_result)#2 (5) {
  ["current_field"]=>
  int(0)
  ["field_count"]=>
  int(2)
  ["lengths"]=>
  NULL
  ["num_rows"]=>
  int(0)
  ["type"]=>
  int(1)
}
```

Aqui se muestra la tabla origen pero enmascarada aun. Seguimos en la búsqueda :)

Comment: Lo más fácil es hacer esto: `SELECT users.nombre 'users.nombre', sucursales.nombre 'sucursales.nombre' FROM users LEFT JOIN sucursales ON sucursales.idsucursales=users.idsucursales`  de ese modo mostrará las columnas así:  `users.nombre` y `sucursales.nombre`.  ¿Hay alguna razón que justifique tu negativa a usar alias? Tendrías que recurrir a procedimientos complicados para ¿quizá?  lograr lo que quieres.

Comment: Hola A.Cedano muchas gracias por tu respuesta; pues te platico, que el interés de esto es realizar un reporteador que se enfoque en la programacion de las consultas sql, donde yo pueda poner cualquier consulta y el sistema me pueda decir a que tabla.campo correponde.

Estaba pensando en hacer a la par un recorrido de la query en si

Tratar de decodificar el SQL por su SELECT c1,c2,c3 FROM y almacenar en un arreglo estos campos, para después recorrer las estructuras de las tablas y comparar los campos

Gracias por tu tiempo :)

Comment: Es importante que las afirmaciones de tu anterior comentario consten en la pregunta y que expliques un poco mejor lo que quieres. Ahora se entiende por qué no querías usar alias. En ese caso puedes valerte de tablas como `schema` para quizá hacer `JOIN` también con ellas obteniendo los nombres de tablas/columnas.

Comment: Voy a trabajar hoy en esto y mañana te platico como fue, pero voy a tomar en cuenta tu observación e integrare a la pregunta esto ultimo por si alguien mas puede aportar. Muchas gracias :)

Comment: ¿Quieres consultas dinámicas?

Comment: La idea mas bien es poder poner cualquier SQL y se obtenga su tabla.campo aunque se usen alias o subquerys, hasta ahora funciona bien sin subquerys

Comment: Rubén, otra aproximación interesante podría ser el uso de [`getColumnMeta()`](http://php.net/manual/es/pdostatement.getcolumnmeta.php)  si usas PDO, o de [`result_metadata`](http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli-stmt.result-metadata.php) si usas mysqli.

Comment: @A.Cedano fijate que si lo uso $T_campos=$resultado->columnCount();
         for($x=0;$x<$T_campos;$x++){
                $meta=$resultado->getColumnMeta($x);
                $arreglo[$x]=$meta['name'];
            } Pero no resuelve el problema de la tabla, lo muestra como nombre,nombre

Comment: Pruébalo en un ámbito de consultas preparadas: `$stmt=$con->prepare($sql);` y luego `$stmt->execute();`.  Ahora prueba esto: `$res = $stmt->result_metadata(); var_dump($res->fetch_fields());`  verás información interesante.

Comment: Me pongo a ello te comento el resultado...

Comment: También, revisa en el Manual, [un ejemplo interesante usando `current_field`](http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli-result.current-field.php), en el área de ejemplos.

Comment: Muy buena idea @A.Cedano modifique la pregunta incluyendo tu sugerencia, aunque no logramos del todo el objetivo nos acercamos  :)

Comment: A nivel de base de datos **no** se puede escoger el nombre que quieres que tenga una columna sin usar un alias (palabra reservada `AS` o poner el alias directamente). Otra cosa es que a nivel de código hagas una trampa y se lo cambies tú.

Comment: @EAmez, muchas gracias por tu aporte en efecto es una trampa en el código, a la fecha no conozco ninguna consulta que lo haga de manera directa.

Comment: @RubenHernandez sin usar alias, lo único que se me ocurre es una `UNION` que sería algo como: `select 'users.nombre', 'sucursales.nombre' from dual UNION select users.nombre, sucursales.nombre from users inner join sucursales [...];`. Esta forma sé que funciona en Oracle, que si no tiene un nombre de columna coge el valor del primer registro y lo utiliza como nombre de columna a la hora de devolver los resultados. Pero no funciona en PostgreSQL.

Comment: @EAmez, no he tenido oportunidad de probarlo con Oracle pero haré algunas pruebas con MySQL y te comento

Answer (score 1):

Yo tambien he tenido hace tiempo que hacer algo similar. Para lograr el nombre de las cabeceras y poder usar esos datos utilizo esta función:

```
//complementaria para recoger nombre de columnas de la consulta
function mysqli_field_name($result, $field_offset){
    $properties = mysqli_fetch_field_direct($result, $field_offset);
    return is_object($properties) ? $properties->name : null;
}
```

En mi caso, como lo utilizaba para la creación de un fichero, la llamaba de esta forma:

```
            //Creamos los titulos de las columnas
            for ($i = 0; $i <mysqli_num_fields($result); $i++) {
                print mysqli_field_name($result,$i) . " ;\t\t";
            }
```

Ahora mismo no estoy seguro de si en la salida al no poner un alias en la consulta mysql tambien te devolverá en formato: tabla.columna

Espero que te ayude